# Ошибки 403 404 502 при выполнении phpinfo()

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404, lubuntu, http-status-code-403

Поставил nginx, mysql-server, php, а вот когда дело дошло до запуска скрипта   info.php

```
<?php

    phpinfo();

?>
```

Пошли ошибки 403 404 502.
Предпологаю, что нужно добавить пользователя с возможностью изменять содержимое папки var/www/ и на пару директорий usr/ .[image: вид терминала]

Comment: phpinfo() ничего не изменяет в файловой системе, так что права на запись ей точно не нужны. А что именно не так смотрите в логах nginx

Comment: directory index of "/var/www/blogOfLife/" is forbidden -> вот это было в error.log

Comment: А вы обращались именно к своей php, т.е. она была явно указана в пути в url ? Такое ощущение, что вы указали просто корень сайта, а настройки nginx не позволили ему предположить, что требуется запуск index.php и он попытался показать содержимое каталога, но показ его содержимого опять же запрещен настройками самого nginx

Comment: если http://blogoflife/www/info.php -> то 404 Not Found nginx/1.15.5 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Опять же в error_log смотрите что именно и где он пытается найти

Comment: Mike спасибо, там проблема была в файле to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed, потому что версия php7.2, вот и его не находило